# expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'boolean'

Tags: c++, c, unix, kernel, linux-device-driver

the following is my .h file

```
4 typedef struct pic_ pic_t; 
5 typedef int32_t status_t; 
6 typedef u_int16_t pic_id_t; 
7 typedef const char* (*pic_flavor_t) (pic_t *); 
8 typedef status_t (*pic_periodic_t) (pic_t *); 
9 typedef status_t (*pic_get_port_info_t) (pic_t *pic, u_int16_t link, void*info, Boolean*need_update); 
11 struct pic_ 
12 { 
13 u_int16_t   nic_slot; 
14 u_int16_t   pic_slot; 
15 u_int32_t   pic_flags; 
16 pic_id_t    pic_id; 
17 u_int16_t   pic_asic_type; 
18 u_int16_t   pic_firstport; 
19 pic_periodic_t  pic_periodic; 
20 pic_flavor_t    pic_flavor; 
21 pic_get_port_info_t pic_get_port_info; 
22 void *pic_context; 
23 };
```

And I'm getting the following error

```
../../../../../src/pfe/common/drivers/rpio/rpio_tunnel_pvt1.h:9: error: expected     declaration specifiers or '...' before 'boolean'
```

I have tried including 
also tried replacing booleand with bool and also with _bool
still no help.
someone please help me out here

Comment: You are missing the closing bracket and the `;` at like 9, is that a copy-paste issue?

Comment: C++ or C? Pick one, please. I strongly suspect C++ is redundant in a question tagged "linux kernel".

Comment: Do you `#include <stdbool.h>`?

Comment: The posted code `Boolean` and the error message `boolean` don't match.

Comment: i corrected my code, it is "boolean" OlafDietsche
yes i did '#include <stdbool.h>" @KlasLindbäck
it is C jrok
SingerOfTheFall, could you please point out where the bracket is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `Boolean` nor `boolean` exist anywhere in the Linux kernel header files.

However, there is a `bool` defined in [linux/types.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/types.h#n29) as

```
typedef _Bool           bool;
```

To access this, you must change `boolean` to `bool` and include `linux/types.h` in your source.

Comment: The standard include file would be `<stdbool.h>`. Including `linux/types.h` directly would make it harder to port the code to non-linux platforms.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:kernel] and [tag:linux-device-driver], therefore the usual standard C includes don't apply here.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not know what name `Boolean` denotes. You need to include the header where this name is defined in this header before referencing to `Boolean`

Comment: @user3409272  There is no such a keyword as a type specifier as boolean in C++. Use bool instead. Or if it is a C program then either _Bool or simply int.